# Creating a custom layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, binary, binary-classification

I'm trying to create a layer in TensorFlow, which works something like this:

[image: bv-layer]

And my implementation looks something, like this:

```
class BinaryLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BinaryLayer, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        w_init = 0.5
        
        self.w = tf.Variable(name="kernel",   initial_value=w_init(dtype='float32'),trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.math.greater(inputs, self.w)
```

But it gives me an error saying **`'float' object is not callable`**

And I also think there will be another problem in the future, which is, it will return `boolean` values, such as: `[[TFT] [TTF] [FFT]]`, but I want something like this: `[[101] [110] [001]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, with:

```
self.w = tf.Variable(name="kernel",   initial_value=w_init,trainable=True)
...
tf.cast(out_tensor_b, tf.float32)
```